# Challenging geometry problem from AMC 2013

Tags: geometry

Question 29 from the senior division of the 2013 Australian mathematics competition.

[image]

I got every question except this one and have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I tried letting QZ=m and PX=4n and I noted angle QZS=angle XZY and angle TXP=angle YXR to try and find similar triangles or some relationship between something but had no luck

Comment: have you tried using vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result does not change as long as we preserve the ratios of segments. Hence we can take, for instance, $PR=QR=18$ and $PQ=36x$ (see figure below).

A first similitude gives then $x$:
$$
(11+3x):3=(11+28x):8.
$$
And a second similitude gives $PT=y$:
$$
(y+8x):8=(y+27x):9.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Applying Menelaus Theorem a few times:

$$\frac{RY}{RQ}\times \frac{QP}{PT}\times\frac{TX}{XY}=1$$

$$\frac{3}{6}\times \frac{QP}{PT}\times\frac{TX}{XY}=1$$

$$\frac{TX}{XY}=\frac{2PT}{QP}...[1]$$

$$\frac{SQ}{ST}\times \frac{TX}{XY}\times\frac{YZ}{ZQ}=1$$

$$\frac{11}{11+QT}\times \frac{TX}{XY}\times\frac{2}{1}=1$$

$$\frac{TX}{XY}=\frac{11+QT}{22}...[2]$$

$$\frac{TX}{XY}=\frac{2PT}{QP}=\frac{11+QT}{22}...[1]\&[2]...[3]$$

$$\frac{PT}{QT}\times \frac{QY}{YR}\times\frac{RX}{XP}=1$$

$$\frac{PT}{QT}\times \frac{3}{3}\times\frac{5}{4}=1$$

$$\frac{PT}{QT}=\frac{PT}{QP+PT}=\frac{4}{5}$$

$$PT=4QP...[4]$$

$$\frac{2PT}{QP}=\frac{11+QT}{22}...[3]\&[4]$$

$$\frac{2\times 4QP}{QP}=\frac{11+QT}{22}$$

$$QT=165$$

$$ST=176$$